# Slightly esoteric gcc error in a simple C program

Tags: c, gcc

I'm starting to learn C++ and as an exercise I'm coding a simple game. While I think my logic is nearly finished, i cannot figure out why gcc is complaining about my code.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void readGuess(int[4]);
int blackScore(int[4], int[4]);
int anotherGame(void);
int whiteScore(int[4],int[4]);
void printScore(int[4],int[4]);

int main(void){
    int codes[5][4] = {{1,8,9,2}, {2,4,6,8}, {1,9,8,3}, {7,4,2,1}, {4,6,8,9}};

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        int guess[4];
        readGuess(guess);
        while(blackScore(guess, codes[i]) != 4) {
            printScore(guess, codes[i]);
            readGuess(guess);
        }

        printf("You have guessed correctly!!");
        if(i<4){
            int another = anotherGame();
            if(!another)
                break;
        }
    }




    return 0;
}
void readGuess(int[4] guess) {
    scanf("%d %d %d %d",&guess,&guess+1,&guess+2,&guess+3);
}

int blackScore(int[4] guess, int[4] code){
    int score = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<4;++i){
        if(code[i]==guess[i]){
            score++;
        }
    }
    return score;
}

int whiteScore(int[] guess, int[] code){
    int score = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<4;++i){
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j<4;++j){
            if(i!=j && (code[i] == guess[i])){
                score++;
            }
        }
    }
    return score;
}

void printScore(int[4] guess, int[4] code){
    printf("(%d,%d)\n",blackScore(guess,code),whiteScore(guess,code));
}

int anotherGame(void){
    while(1){
        printf("Would you like to play another game? [Y/N]\n");
        char result;
        result = getchar();
        if(result == 'Y')
            return 1;
        else if (result == 'N')
            return 0;
    }
}
```

And these are the errors:

```
testSource.c:34:23: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘guess’
testSource.c:38:23: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘guess’
testSource.c:49:22: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘guess’
testSource.c:63:24: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘guess’
testSource.c: In function ‘anotherGame’:
testSource.c:70:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
```

Can you guys help me figure out what the issues are?

Comment: `int blackScore(int[4] guess, int[4] code){` does not look right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `int[4] guess` to `int *guess`.

Comment: That fixed it! Strange, my notes mentioned that function(int[] arg) is the correct way to pass an array by reference.

Comment: @freefrag: Then throw your notes away.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters should not declare a size of the array. Use `int guess[]` instead of `int[4] guess` in your parameters.

Also `result` needs to be declared in the top of `anotherGame` unless you use the `-c99` switch for GCC.

Answer (score 0):

You have your argument declaration mixed up with Java I think:

```
void readGuess(int[4] guess) {
```

It should be

```
void readGuess(int guess[]) {
```

You have same problem with the other functions.

Also, the prototypes doesn't always match the actual functions, for example `whiteScore`.

Comment: Didn't downvote you, but array sizes in function signatures as such are meaningless and the compiler will ignore them. So, it's probably better to say just `int guess[]` as some others mentioned, to not be misleading.

Comment: @FatalError For single-dimension arrays yes, but for multi-dimension arrays the array size is still needed. Updated my answer.